# Runtime of prime factorization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, primes

> Consider an algorithm that takes in an integer `N` and divides out all
>   the factors of 2, then 3, then 4, all the way up to about `sqrt(N)`.
>   If it takes unit time to add, subtract, multiply, and divide integers,
>   how fast is this algorithm? What about if it takes `Theta(n)` time to
>   add, subtract, multiply, and divide two `n`-digit binary numbers?

---

My thoughts:

In order to better understand the problem, I first wrote some pseudocode outlining the algorithm. I think it looks something like this.

```
factorize(N) {
   for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(N); i++) {
        let r be the remainder obtained by dividing N by i.
        while (r == 0) {
          N = N / i;
          print i       # Print the prime factors of N.
        }
    }
 }
```

I'm pretty sure the algorithm is `O(sqrt(N))` just from trial-and-error (plugging in values). I think this worst-case is exhibited when `N` is prime. However, I'm not completely sure about this.

Now I'm also confused about how this runtime changes if it takes `Theta(n)` time to add, subtract, multiply, and divide two binary digits. This seems a lot harder to analyze for some reason since we're performing a division on every iteration. If I had to guess, I would say `O(N^(3/2))`, which is just my old answer multiplied by `N`, but I'm even less sure about this answer.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're quite correct on the first algorithm: worst-case is when `N` is prime, and you have no factors.  Your loop runs for `sqrt(N)-1` iterations, **O(sqrt(N))**

For the second algorithm, the missing insight is that the quantity of digits in `N` is `ceil(log(N, base=2))`.  For computing complexity, simply use `n = log(N)`.

From what you've already covered, I expect that you can finish from here: your division operation is now **O(log N)** rather than **O(1)**.